# Why does my total number of votes differ in three places?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, caching

The title basically says it all. I was looking at my profile, and I noticed that there are three places that I can see the number of votes I have cast.

1. There is a badge for voting a certain number of times (Civic Duty) - 94.
2. In the impact section, it tells me how many times I have voted - 92.
3. Under the votes tab, I can see total votes - 93.

You can see the all this in these pictures:

[image: First and Second]
[image: Third]

Am I misunderstanding how votes are calculated in all three places? Or is it simply a time-related thing that will get resolved (caching or something like that).

Comment: hint: one word, first of your name

Comment: How often does this caching-reset (or whatever the term for it) happen?

Comment: You are being downvoted at a faster rate than you can check the values:)

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It's caching. Blame caching. All world problems are the result of caching. Your addiction to stack overflow is worsening because of caching. Programming fails as a result of caching. Comments don't add fast enough because of caching. Stack Overflow displays false profile information because of caching. You have different numbers of votes because of caching. Pings don't ping you in time from caching. The answer at http://shouldiblamecaching.com is invalid due to caching. Within the years, caching will be replaced with something much better it may be out of the world: **skeeting.**

Comment: The difference in my vote totals seems a little too far out to be caching related o_0 http://i.imgur.com/9lgbKhb.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - you are not comparing the same things.

Comment: @Oded I'm looking at the locations the OP mentioned. Where should I be checking? If I'm not comparing the same thing then at the very least it's a little confusing in the UI to have two different values labelled the same: http://i.imgur.com/ccKyYSO.png?1

Comment: OP is looking at the summary tab of the profile activity tab. You are looking at the votes one, @RoryMcCrossan - the summary shows the counts of up and down votes (which is what the number in the impact area is for, as the tooltip shows: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Kv3.png)

Comment: @Oded So what is the difference between the two? Do they _both_ not refer to up and down votes? I don't think I have cast any other votes besides up and down votes, yet mine still differ currently by 3. (92 in the bottom "Votes Cast" and 95 in the Impact 's "votes cast." Is this still caching?

Comment: @CacheStaheli - there are more vote types than just up and down - the votes sub-tab of the activity tab can list them all. What you see in the summary will add up to what you see in the impact section "votes cast".

Comment: @Oded And if the all votes is less than the votes cast? 110 (only counted from 92 upvotes and 18 downvotes). The Summary votes are 118. Still caching?

Comment: @CacheStaheli - I don't see those numbers. I see 118 in the impact section. The summary says 93 up and 25 down. 93 + 25 = 118. How do you count your "all votes"? Are you talking about the votes tab? Something specific there (again - just up and downvotes tabs should match up)?

Comment: @Oded That's not what I see, so I guess it is caching. They just haven't matched for days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at your profile right now, I see all the numbers matching up - they are all at 95 right now.

As others have said - these bits are all cached, so the display can get out of sync (normally for a few minutes, though if more votes happen in the meanwhile...).

Comment: Yup. It's corrected for me now too.

Comment: Edit: not so much, see comment on question above.